# Computing with length units in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate the volume of a room and my measurements are given in meters.

```
ex.
3,15m
4,5m
17,6m
```

I need to multiply them and instead of a result, Excel returns an error. I have been searching on the internet and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Can you show us what your formula looks like?

Comment: sure my formula only multiplies

Comment: these 3 numbers are in 3 different cells so all my formula does is =C1*C2*C3

Comment: remove the "m" letters

Comment: yes that m is the problem I cannot find a way to specify it

Comment: yes i know but the exercise demands that "m" letters stay

Comment: and not only that the result has to be in m^3

Comment: You could remove the "m" and then give your cell a custom format of `0.00"m"` so that Excel displays the "m" but treats the number as 3.15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the `m`, `--` to convert the result to a number, and `PRODUCT` to multiply:

```
=PRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(C1:C3,"m",""))
```

[image]

This is an array formula, so depending on your version of Excel you may need to confirm the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Though as already suggested, removing the `m` and giving your original cells a custom format of `0.00"m"` is another option. Then straight multiplication will work.

Comment: okay thanks for your answer follow up question my result also has to be in the correct unit in this case cubic meters (m^3)